# PERL precision error when computing base-10 log characteristic

Tags: perl, floating-point, precision

I realize FP representations of non-power-of-two numbers always have errors but this...

```
% perl -e 'print int(log(1000)/log(10))."\n"'
2
% perl -e 'print (log(1000)/log(10))."\n"'
3
% perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 2 (v5.22.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

...oy... what would be a workaround for finding the characteristic (integer part) of a base-10 (or arbitrary base) logarithm? Thanks!

**EDIT**: POSIX::floor() produces the same result. So the question stands, how do I compute the characteristic of a logarithm if I'm running into rounding errors?

Comment: The [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html) doesn't round.  You can use `sprintf "%.N", $float` (or with `printf`)

Comment: Yes, but how do I solve my problem? POSIX::float() rounds and produces the same results.

Comment: What is the output and behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @PeterT  Than it may be unclear to us what your problem is -- what precise output do you want? A logarithm characteristic is the integer part, and I thought that the answer by [dawg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) tells you all you need. Btw, please remember that fractional powers really involve roots, which brings in branches and branch cuts of a complex function.  (You _can_ ignore that -- if appropriate for what you are doing.)

Comment: I want to compute the characteristic for a base-10 log in PERL. The characteristic is the integer part of the logarithm. So naturally I tried using int() on float, thinking it would return the integer portion, but I clearly don't understand what int() does, because as my example shows log1000/log10 should equal exactly 3 by definition, and int of log(1000)/log(10) should also be 3. But it is 2. Hence my confusion. @zdim

Answer (score 3):

You need a lot more than the default decimal places before `2.999....` is not rounded to 3.

Try:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%.17f\n",log(1000)/log(10)'
2.99999999999999956
```

And `int` is the floor of a float:

```
$ perl -e 'print int(2.999)."\n"'
2
```

---

The standard way of dealing with the floating part and integer part of a float is contained in the [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module.

You can separate the integer part and float part with `modf`:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e '($fp, $ip)=modf(3.14); print "$fp $ip\n"'
0.14 3
```

Or, in your case:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e '($fp, $ip)=modf(log(1000)/log(10)); printf "%.17f %i\n",$fp,$ip '
0.99999999999999956 2
```

You can also use `ceil`, `floor`, `fxexp`, and `round` for standard versions of those functions.

If *precision* is your concern, potentially an easy partial fix is to use the [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) library:

```
$ perl -Mbignum -e 'printf "%.30f\n",log(1000)/log(10)'
3.000000000000000000000000000000
```

Or, as a pragma:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -e 'use bigint; ($fp, $ip)=modf(log(1000)/log(10)); printf "%.45f %i\n",$fp,$ip'
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 3
```

Or, since `log` is a [transcendental function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalFunction.html), use a symbolic math package.

Comment: Thanks for showing me modf. Sorry to be so dense but because int() of log(x)/log(10) with x=1000 should always be exactly 3 I'm a bit confused. And if x = 1001 the integer part should be 3 as well. And x = 999 it should be 2. Soooo. what's a general solution that is continuous that provides the correct expected answer?

Comment: Oooorrrr, should i just -always- pass floating point #s through sprintf() to trim to some precision in between computational steps? Or should I be using a float library? Or should I be comparing to an epsilon and testing for errors?

Comment: Well `log` is a [Transcendental Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalFunction.html) and the best you can do on a computer is either a polynomial approximation (which is what `log` does) or use a symbolic math package such as [Math::Symbolic](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Math-Symbolic-0.612/lib/Math/Symbolic.pm) or others of that type